# draft vs rough draft

Tags: meaning

According to Merriam-Webster, draft means a preliminary sketch.

> draft n. a preliminary sketch, outline or version. e.g. the author's first draft

Interestingly, Merriam-Webster also provides a definition for "rough draft".

> rough draft, a first version of something. e.g. I just completed a rough draft of my speech

Q1. is "rough draft" used ONLY for "a first draft" (i.e. not for "a second draft"?)

Q2. is "rough" somewhat redundant, since "draft" by definition is preliminary ?

Answer (score 1):

As good writing is a [recursive](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/recursive?s=t) endeavor, *a* first draft is not necessarily identical to *the* first draft. How rough or polished a preliminary version of a written work may seem rests soley with the author or editor, not some objective quality inherent, say, in gemstones, from which the metaphor of rough to polished is drawn.

Some writers, particularly journalists, can turn out print-ready copy in one go; others require several versions. With computer word processing and internet publication, a written text is theoretically never in a fixed form, that is, the final polish could remain forever elusive.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick google I found that some other dictionaries agree with Merriam Webster that a "rough draft" is a first draft: [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rough--draft) and [oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/rough_draft).

I disagree. I don't see "rough draft" as a compound noun, I see "draft" as a noun and "rough" as an adjective, meaning:

> 16. not polished or perfected in any detail; rudimentary; not elaborate

<sup>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/rough)</sup>

Therefore a "rough draft" is "a draft that is not perfected in any detail".

I can see the following conversation:

> *Manager*: Bob, did you manage to do anything with the rough draft of that report which Alice started?
>
> *Bob*: Yeah, but I only had 10 minutes for it last night. I added in a few chapter titles which Alice hadn't included, but I haven't put any detail in; it's still a **rough draft**.

"Rough" here isn't redundant, it's an intensifier. A "draft" might be preliminary, but a "rough draft" is *very* preliminary. You might start with a "rough draft", edit it into a "reasonable draft", edit it again into a "final draft" and then turn it into a "published version".

Comment: +1, though as KarlG notes, the word "first" in *first draft* might not be completely literal.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous profession, as an HM Schools Inspector, I had to produce two kinds of document.  The first was a a report on a school.  It had to follow a prescribed format according to prescribed procedures.  In such a case there was (and is) no place for a *rough draft*.  It would be a waste of my time, for the effective use of which I was properly accountable.  The first draft has to be close to the finished report but for a few minor corrections and clarifications.

At other times I might have to write a guidance paper on some aspect of (say teaching).  In such a case I might submit a *rough draft* to my line manager or even a trusted colleague, just to check that it was broadly along the right lines, sufficiently comprehensive, taking account of any relevant policies, and covering ground worth covering.  I would not have checked it with great care.  So the word *sketch*, as in the first definition you cite is just the word.

There is, I think, a genuine difference between a rough draft and a *first* draft.  Moreover, if you told me you were sending me a ‘draft’ of a book or article, I should expect something more carefully worked out than a **rough** draft.

The status of numbered drafts, however, is today a trickier matter than it was before computers.  Many save documents as ‘draft 1, 2, ... n’ as a means of version control.  In such a case, the rough draft (if there is one) might be saved as ‘draft 1’.  I have not seen a file name with ‘draft rough’ in it.